# Cannot get certain ListItem's `ContentType`

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, content-type, csom

I am having a frustrating issue with my SharePoint CSOM c# program.

I am needing to get the type of a list item. In order to do this, i first use

```
clientContext.Load(listItem.ContentType);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Then I get the content type's name with:

```
listItem.ContentType.Name
```

For many of my list items, I get an error message:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerObjectNullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object on server. The object is associated with property ContentType.

What's up with that? Why are some list items without a content type name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Sharepoint/en-US/53c2d22e-8915-45e2-aec9-0f026c5e20be/where-can-i-report-csom-issues-to?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Please using the code below to get the content type.

```
var ct = list.ContentTypes.GetById(listItem["ContentTypeId"].ToString());
ctx.Load(ct);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
Console.WriteLine(ct.Name);
```